# Onshow event of datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want add class to datepicker when display. I wrote this code but don't work .

how to do this?

```
$(targetEl).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "-100:-13",
      defaultDate: "-13y",
      regional: '',
      isRTL: true,
      onShow: function () { $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("DatePikerEN"); }

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `onShow` event isn't mentioned in the documentation. Use `beforeShow` instead

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-100:-13",
        defaultDate: "-13y",
        regional: '',
        isRTL: true,
        beforeShow: function () { 
            alert('show');
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("DatePikerEN"); 
        }
 });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/58rs7fze/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Marked Answer totally worked !!

But if in some case there more then one datepicker exist 
then you should use instance of current datepicker and target only one datepicker control

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-100:-13",
        defaultDate: "-13y",
        regional: '',
        isRTL: true,
        beforeShow: function (elem,dp) { 
            dp.dpDiv.addClass("DatePikerEN"); 
        }
 });
```